# What is the best way to ban an user from all the servers the bot is in without api spamming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

is there a better way than this one to ban an user from all the servers the bot is in without api spamming?

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.ban(targetID))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**:

This is against Discord's ToS, and you should not use it.

**CODE**:

I will still provide code for the sake of knowledge.

You can use `setInterval()` to wait an amount of time before banning.

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => {
  setInterval(() => {
    a.members.ban(targetID);
  }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: “*This is against Discord's ToS, and you should not use it.*” I don’t doubt this, but can you provide a source for this claim?

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/policies-and-agreements/developer-policy

"modify a Discord user’s account without explicit permission from the Discord user. For example, you may not add a Discord user to a Discord (also known as a “server”) unless that Discord user expressly approved joining that Discord (such as when using a "group finder" app);"

Banning an user across multiple guilds that you're not the owner of falls under this.

Comment: this if for banning scammers in market servers, means that all the owners agree with that, do not worry.